# Wi fi linking broadband to my android

Tags: wi-fi

i am using bsnl broad band for my pc iwant to use it for my android data connection for my   lenova S5000-H MODEL, What network mode Ihave to select eighther GSM or WCDMA TO GET  WLAN?

Comment: Is your PC Wi-Fi enabled? If yes, then create a hotspot on it. If no,  then look for "Reverse tethering".

Answer (score 0):

BSNL providing routers with WIFI connections.
You don't need to TURN ON **DATA** for wifi connection OR not required **network modes**, Try to access data by turning on **wifi** of your device.